# Facebook SDK logging in user without needing to go to the login url

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

For some reason, whenever I am logged in Facebook (i.e. facebook.com) the user is automatically authenticated on my website (after 2 refreshes) which is using the Facebook SDK. But the strange thing is the user does not need to click on the generated login url that I generate using `getLoginUrl()` What's happening here? Below is my function for checking if the user is logged in or not.

```
function IsUserLoggedIn()
{
    $ci=& get_instance();

          try
          {
            $me = $ci->facebook->api('/me');
            $user = $ci->facebook->getUser();

              if ($me&&$user)
                {
                  //These var dumps show the right info.
                  var_dump($user);
                  var_dump($me);
                  return TRUE;   
                }


          } 
          catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            //User is not logged in


             $ci->load->library('session');

                    $user_id = $ci->session->userdata('user_id');
                    $is_user_logged_in =  $ci->session->userdata('logged_in');

                    if(($user_id != FALSE)&&($is_user_logged_in != FALSE))
                    {
                        return TRUE;
                    }
                    else
                    {   
                        return FALSE;
                    }
          }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user is logged in, via Facebook, the SDK that you have loaded, automatically checks the associated facebook cookie, so the user is already logged in on your website also:

```
try
          {
            $me = $ci->facebook->api('/me'); //The user has an active session, no matter if that was from facebook login or from website login using Facebook SDK
            $user = $ci->facebook->getUser(); //So you successfully get the user data

              if ($me&&$user)
                {
                  //These var dumps show the right info.
                  var_dump($user);
                  var_dump($me);
                  return TRUE;   
                }


          }
```

Comment: How does that make sense? If the SDK picks up Facebook cookies, then what's the point of authentication. Why doesn't it only pick up your App Cookies?

Comment: That is exactly the point. To not have to log in again to a website when your Facebook Session is active. If you want to override this, just use CI to set another session key. Check for that session on your isLoggedIn function (except the facebook cookie) and set it, when user hits log in.